# How to customize authentication to my own set of tables in asp.net web api 2?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

In the default AccountController created I see

```
    public AccountController()
        : this(Startup.UserManagerFactory(), Startup.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat)
    {
    }
```

In Startup.Auth.cs I see

```
    UserManagerFactory = () => 
                new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>());
```

Seems like the implementation of **UserStore** comes from **Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework**.

So, to customize the authentication do I have to implement my own version of UserStore like

```
 class MYSTUFFUserStore<IdentityUser> : UserStore<IdentityUser>
 {
 }
```

and override the methods and then do this in Startup.Auth.cs

```
UserManagerFactory = () => 
               new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new MYSTUFFUserStore<IdentityUser>());
```

I am looking for a correct way to customize the authentication.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Assuming your table is called `AppUser`, convert your own `AppUser` domain object to `IUser(using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity)` like this

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
public class AppUser : IUser
{
    //Existing database fields
    public long AppUserId { get; set; }
    public string AppUserName { get; set; }
    public string AppPassword { get; set; }

    public AppUser()
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();  
    }

    [Ignore]
    public virtual string Id { get; set; }         
    [Ignore]
    public string UserName
    {
        get
        {
            return AppUserName;
        }
        set
        {
            AppUserName = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Implement the `UserStore` object like this

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
public class UserStoreService 
         : IUserStore<AppUser>, IUserPasswordStore<AppUser>
{
    CompanyDbContext context = new CompanyDbContext();

    public Task CreateAsync(AppUser user)
    {            
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task DeleteAsync(AppUser user)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<AppUser> FindByIdAsync(string userId)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<AppUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
    {
        Task<AppUser> task = context.AppUsers.Where(
                              apu => apu.AppUserName == userName)
                              .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        return task;
    }

    public Task UpdateAsync(AppUser user)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        context.Dispose();
    }

    public Task<string> GetPasswordHashAsync(AppUser user)
    {
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("user");
        }

        return Task.FromResult(user.AppPassword);
    }

    public Task<bool> HasPasswordAsync(AppUser user)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(user.AppPassword != null);
    }

    public Task SetPasswordHashAsync(AppUser user, string passwordHash)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

}
```

If you have your own custom password hashing you will also need to implement `IPasswordHasher`. Below is an example where there is no hashing of the password(Oh no!)

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
public class MyPasswordHasher : IPasswordHasher
{
    public string HashPassword(string password)
    {
        return password;
    }

    public PasswordVerificationResult VerifyHashedPassword
                  (string hashedPassword, string providedPassword)
    {
        if (hashedPassword == HashPassword(providedPassword))
            return PasswordVerificationResult.Success;
        else
            return PasswordVerificationResult.Failed;
    }
}
```

In Startup.Auth.cs replace

```
UserManagerFactory = () => 
     new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>());
```

with

```
    UserManagerFactory = () => 
     new UserManager<AppUser>(new UserStoreService()) { PasswordHasher = new MyPasswordHasher() };
```

In `ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs`, replace `IdentityUser` with `AppUser`

In `AccountController.cs`, replace `IdentityUser` with `AppUser` and delete all the external authentication methods like `GetManageInfo` and `RegisterExternal` etc.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but how I can get `AppUser` from another controller for the current request?

Comment: `User.Identity.Name` will give you the username in an authenticated request.

Comment: Sunil, can you explain why does custom class "AppUser" need to inplement built-in interface "IUser"?

Comment: @Thomas.Benz here is a snippet from an article I found useful:

"Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager<T> where T: IUser
This class allows to create, delete and find users  as well as to create identities. An identity is created for a user and can be used to make authorization and authentication decisions."

The idea here is to use some/most of the built-in features of ASP.NET Identity and then override/replace what you need with a custom implementation - at least that's what I have done here thanks to Sunil's answer