# Token based login logic change in ASP.NET Identity 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I am building a SPA app using WebAPI 2 backend. I am using the new ASP.NET Identity 2.0 for authorization and authentication. To login I call the /Token URL which returns the token which I use for subsequent API calls. Now all this works fine.

Now I need to make some changes to the login/authentication process where I want to check if email is confirmed and also the user is active (both DB fields) before returning the token. But I am unable to find which method is being called for authorization. I thought it was the GetExternalLogin method in AccountController but it does not seem to be so.

Can someone tell me where I need to change the login logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to implement your own UserStore to implement your own authentication logic.
Refer [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20529401/)

If you don't want to do that may be, in `ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs` find this function `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials`. After this line

```
IdentityUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, 
                                                context.Password);
```

you may be able to squeeze in some custom logic like

```
if (IsEmailConfirmed(user) == false)
{
   context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
   return;
}
```

Comment: I used the second option and it worked like a charm!