# asp.net web api using existing db for token authentication and user authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, oauth-2.0

I need to build a RESTfull web service using OAuth, bearer `access_token` and `refresh_token`. Authentication and authorization should be done by checking existing sql db.

The web api template, provided by VS2013 writes/reads in/from its own local sqlexpress db by this connectionString:

```
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApiTest-20150423094253.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApiTest-20150423094253;Integrated Security=True"
```

After hours of googling, I just got tutorials and examples, which do not match with my issue.

So how can I bind my db into the project for authentication/athorization?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this issue?

Comment: No. Do you know the answer?

Comment: I"m in the middle of doing it now.  Its a bit of a complicated answer and I dont have it complete yet, but I've received help from [these](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28526641/2589202) [answers](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/).  Once I get through it I'll try to create an answer that is not too long.

Comment: I've found [this post](http://codebetter.com/johnvpetersen/2012/04/02/making-your-asp-net-web-apis-secure/) and it is exactly what I want.  I think it is what you're describing here also.  The key is in his `TokenValidationAttribute` there is a line `AuthorizedUserRepository.GetUsers...` this just needs to be replaced with a query to your database.  Seems to be much simpler than the OWIN stuff.